# Take string from local file, insert into input on website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension to automate/ease a few tasks at work. One thing we regularly have to do is sign in to customer modems with a seeded Arris password-of-the-day. I've been able to load the text file containing the password-of-the-day sorted by date and get the password relevant to the current date, but right now we have to manually open the network drive, locate the file, find the current date (every potd for the year is generated and split between 4 files by 3 month groups), and then copy and paste. Not a *massive* inconvenience, but I'd like to insert that into the password field automatically if at all possible.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Web Kit",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Modifications for web-based tools",
"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://example.com"],
        "css": ["tickets.css"],
        "js": ["tickets.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["https://example.com"],
        "js": ["iglass.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
        "css": ["iglass.css"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["gateway.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["file:///*"],
        "js": ["potd.js"]
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "file:///home/shea/potd.txt"
],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**gateway.js**

This script checks that the domain matches a Class A private IP range and fills out some information accordingly.

```
var user = "technician";
var potd;
var site = location.hostname;
var regex = new RegExp("(10)(\.([2]([0-5][0-5]|[01234][6-9])|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3}");
var match = site.match(regex);
if (match != null) {
    document.getElementById("username").value = user;
    document.getElementById("password").value = potd;
}
else {
    console.log("Not a gateway login.")
}
```

**potd.js**

This file parses potd.txt for a line where the initial 8 characters match the current date, then grabs the last 10 for the password of the day.

```
// We can load all the POTD files as an array and check them one at a time
// if (location == file) can be nested in a for loop where file is then file[i]

file = "file:///home/shea/potd.txt";

var date = new Date();
var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
if (month.length < 2) {
    month = "0" + month;
}
var day = date.getDate().toString();
if (day.length < 2) {
    day = "0" + day;
}
var year = (date.getFullYear().toString()).slice(-2);
var dateStr = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
if (location == file) {
    var content = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
    var lines = content.split('\n');
    for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        var potd = lines[i].substr(10);
        if (lines[i].substr(0, 8) == dateStr) {
            alert(potd);
            if (!potd) {
                console.log("Something went wrong, no POTD stored...");
            }
            else {
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'date': dateStr}, function() {
                    console.log('Setting saved');
                });
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'potd': potd}, function() {
                    console.log('Setting 2 saved');
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    console.log("Not the potd file");
}
```

You can see where I've tried to use `chrome.storage.sync` but honestly I don't fully understand it and can't seem to get it working.

TL;DR I want to take a string from the `potd.txt` text file and insert it into a text field in http://10.*.*.*

I have a feeling it may not work because these files are not on the same domain, but I figured if anyone could help me, SO could.

Comment: There's a debugger in browser's devtools so you can set a breakpoint and when it triggers you can inspect the variable while stepping the code line by line. Without seeing the potd.txt file or without trying the extension I'm not sure we can help so you need to debug it and determine where exactly it fails. BTW your web_accessible_resources does nothing as it can only list your extension's local resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems that maybe I'm going to have to package the text files with the extension. I was hoping to avoid that in case the extension were to be redistributed or something.

Comment: You can access the file contents via XHR/fetch to its file:// URL in your background script (not the content script) if 1) you add the URL to "permissions", 2) your users are willing to enable file access in the details of the installed extension on chrome://extensions page.